# calling webservice asynchronously in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, web-services, asynchronous

I am trying to call this webservice asynchrounously in vb.net. So on the aspx side i added this property async="true". Now on the vb.net code side i have this function inside my webservice that i am calling.
So -

```
dim as as webservice.webstring
as.functionasync(param1, param2)
```

Now when i run the page, i can see that it wont call the webservice after a timegap. 
Should i add .thread.sleep()?
Do i require the beginAsyn function and the EndAsyn function.
I'm using asp.net 3.5 with IIS7

Answer (score 1):

First, please read [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx) about how the asynchronous pages work in ASP.NET.

Second, you need to have an asynchronous method in your web-service. Please read [this HOWTO article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98t3s469.aspx) about how to create such methods.

This is how your implementation of the async page could look like:

```
private _as as WebService.WebString = Nothing

Public Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    AddOnPreRenderCompleteAsync(New BeginEventHandler(BeginCallingWebService),
        New EndEventHandler(EndCallingWebService));
End Sub

Private Function BeginCallingWebService(Byval sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs, ByVal cb As AsyncCallback, ByVal state As Object)
    _as = New WebService.WebString()

    Return _as.BeginMyMethod(cb, state)
End Function

Private Sub EndCallingWebService(ByVal ar as IAsyncResult)
    Dim result As MyWebServiceResult = _as.EndMyMethod(ar)

    ' Process the result of the web-service method
End Sub
```

Hope this will help you.